# How do I get Nokogiri to understand my namespaces?

Tags: xml, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have the following XML document:

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest ID="123456789" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="200904051217">
  <saml:NameID>@NOT_USED@</saml:NameID>
  <samlp:SessionIndex>abcdefg</samlp:SessionIndex>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

I'd like to get the content of the `SessionIndex` (that is, 'abcdefg') out of it.  I've tried this:

```
XPATH_QUERY = "LogoutRequest[@ID][@Version='2.0'][IssueInstant]/SessionIndex"
SAML_XMLNS  = 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion'
SAMLP_XMLNS = 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'

require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.xpath(XPATH_QUERY, 'saml' => SAML_XMLNS, 'samlp' => SAMLP_XMLNS)
```

but I get the following errors:

```
Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Namespace prefix samlp on LogoutRequest is not defined
Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Namespace prefix saml on NameID is not defined
Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Namespace prefix samlp on SessionIndex is not defined
```

I've tried adding the namespaces to the XPath query, but that doesn't change anything.

Why can't I convince Nokogiri that the namespaces are valid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't look like the namespaces in this document are correctly declared - there should be `xmlns:samlp` and `xmlns:saml` attributes on the root node.  In cases like this, Nokogiri essentially ignores the namespaces (as it can't map them to URIs or URNs), so your XPath works if you remove them, i.e.

```
doc.xpath(XPATH_QUERY)
```

Comment: That seems to give me the same errors ... in some situations.  Doing it literally in irb works fine, but running my specs still blows up. Garr.

Comment: Got it! Nokogiri returns an "error" node that wraps the node that it found, but it _really_did_find_the_node_!

Answer (score 11):

I see a two different options for you:

1. Remove all the namespaces

   http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document#remove_namespaces%21-instance_method

   Brute force way of doing it. Could lead to problems where there are namespace collisions.
2. Use collect_namespaces

   http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document#collect_namespaces-instance_method

   A much better solution.
   You could use this once to identify the namespaces (say in irb) and hard-code them.

   OR

   Use it at runtime, and supply it as the second argument to https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#xpath-instance_method