# Parsing XML with Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing

I'm way new to working with XML but just had a need dropped in my lap. I have been given an usual (to me) XML format. There are colons within the tags.

```
<THING1:things type="Container">
  <PART1:Id type="Property">1234</PART1:Id>
  <PART1:Name type="Property">The Name</PART1:Name>
</THING1:things>
```

It is a large file and there is much more to it than this but I hope this format will be familiar to someone. Does anyone know a way to approach an XML document of this sort?

I'd rather not just write a brute-force way of parsing the text but I can't seem to make any headway with REXML or Hpricot and I suspect it is due to these unusual tags.

my ruby code:

```
    require 'hpricot'
    xml = File.open( "myfile.xml" )

    doc = Hpricot::XML( xml )

   (doc/:things).each do |thg|
     [ 'Id', 'Name' ].each do |el|
       puts "#{el}: #{thg.at(el).innerHTML}"
     end
   end
```

...which is just lifted from: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/12/09/parsing-xml-with-hpricot/

And I figured I would be able to figure some stuff out from here but this code returns nothing. It doens't error. It just returns.

Comment: I take it line 1 is supposed to be <THING1:things type="Container">, not <THING1:things>type="Container">?

Comment: Can you show us your Hpricot attempt?  It _can_ handle namespaces, and it's easier and probably more instructive for us to help you figure out what's wrong with your attempt, rather than try to start you off fresh.

Comment: I really don't have much of an attempt at this point. Just trying to emulate a tutorial. I will edit the post to include.

Comment: For the record, hpricot is no longer being maintained. We're all using nokogiri now.

Comment: `THING1` and `PART1` are XML namespaces and are supposed to be declared. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace

Answer (score 95, accepted):

As @pguardiario mentioned, [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) is the de facto XML and HTML parsing library. If you wanted to print out the `Id` and `Name` values in your example, here is how you would do it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml_str = <<EOF
<THING1:things type="Container">
  <PART1:Id type="Property">1234</PART1:Id>
  <PART1:Name type="Property">The Name</PART1:Name>
</THING1:things>
EOF

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_str)

thing = doc.at_xpath('//things')
puts "ID   = " + thing.at_xpath('//Id').content
puts "Name = " + thing.at_xpath('//Name').content
```

A few notes:

- `at_xpath` is for matching one thing. If you know you have multiple items, you want to use `xpath` instead.
- Depending on your document, namespaces can be problematic, so calling `doc.remove_namespaces!` can help (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3533784/73492) for a brief discussion).
- You can use the `css` methods instead of `xpath` if you're more comfortable with those.
- Definitely play around with this in `irb` or `pry` to investigate methods.

### Resources

- [Parsing an HTML/XML document](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html)
- [Getting started with Nokogiri](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/getting-started-with-nokogiri)

### Update

To handle multiple items, you need a root element, and you need to remove the `//` in the `xpath` query.

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml_str = <<EOF
<root>
  <THING1:things type="Container">
    <PART1:Id type="Property">1234</PART1:Id>
    <PART1:Name type="Property">The Name1</PART1:Name>
  </THING1:things>
  <THING2:things type="Container">
    <PART2:Id type="Property">2234</PART2:Id>
    <PART2:Name type="Property">The Name2</PART2:Name>
  </THING2:things>
</root>
EOF

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_str)
doc.xpath('//things').each do |thing|
  puts "ID   = " + thing.at_xpath('Id').content
  puts "Name = " + thing.at_xpath('Name').content
end
```

This will give you:

```
Id   = 1234
Name = The Name1

ID   = 2234
Name = The Name2
```

If you are more familiar with CSS selectors, you can use this nearly identical bit of code:

```
doc.css('things').each do |thing|
  puts "ID   = " + thing.at_css('Id').content
  puts "Name = " + thing.at_css('Name').content
end
```

Comment: This is great. I have it working for one item. It seems to pull the first item but not the others--as you said. Can you give an example of how to output all of the 'things'? There are about 10 of them.

Comment: @B5Fan74 I have updated my answer with an example. Does that help? You need to add some kind of root element, which your XML file probably has. You then need to remove the // from the xpath query (or use the CSS interface, which I prefer). There's a [handy example](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) in Nokogiri's docs on searching, so I hope that's useful too.

Comment: Updating... Link moved to: https://www.engineyard.com/blog/getting-started-with-nokogiri

Comment: `remove_namespaces!` saved me! Why is it sometimes necessary?

Comment: @jayqui It all depends on your document, and how you're writing your selectors. The [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document#remove_namespaces%21-instance_method) gives a little more info on the behavior.

Comment: Running your first example gives `undefined method `at_xpath' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @reducingactivity You're right! I guess Nokogiri has updated its handling in the last 9 years. I haven't worked in XML/Nokogiri in a long time, so from a quick IRB session, something like this could work, but it doesn't use xpath or anything smart. ``` doc.xpath("*").detect { |x| x.name =~ /:things\z/ }```. However, I think the correct solution is to define namespaces on each `THING` in the XML and update the Ruby code accordingly. The XML structure may need to change quite a bit.

Answer (score 51):

If in a Rails environment, the `Hash` object is extended and one can take advantage of the the method `from_xml`:

```
xml = File.open("myfile.xml")
data = Hash.from_xml(xml)
```

Comment: `from_xml` is not a native Hash method, it's part of Rails / ActiveSupport. If you're in that environment, it works fine.

Comment: this only works in rails environment, not working with plain ruby

Comment: @YakobUbaidi note the first five words of the post.

Comment: YMMV. This does not always convert child data structures that you expect/need to be hashes to hashes. It may instead convert those nested children to Arrays, in which case you lose the keys.