# Ruby functions to send Twilio fields from XML feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, twilio

I'm Ruby n00b, so please excuse my first question.

I've got my Rails environment up on a web server up, and now I am trying to find a Ruby functions (methods?) that would allow me to do the following:

Function 1

- suck in an XML feed from another website
- cherry pick a particular field from that XML field (e.g. email addr or phone)

Function 2

- send that particular XML field to phone number via Twilio.

Any suggestions on where to start would be helpful.  (Even if it's to tell me to RTFM)

Comment: You need to read the docs on Twilio and you need to learn about Xpath or whatever the Ruby equivalent is to parse XML.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool; thanks, emodendroket.  I will look that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first function, you don't need to do anything with Twilio.  I presume you want to parse an XML feed to get specific data from it.

You can use a gem like nokogiri to parse XML, have a look at this similar SO question to learn how:
[Parsing XML with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198239/parsing-xml-with-ruby)

There's tons of other resources on parsing XML using ruby here to:
https://www.google.ca/search?q=parse+xml+ruby&rlz=1C1CHFX_enCA552CA552&oq=parse+xml+ruby&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3359j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

For your second function, this is where you'll actually be using Twilio.  First off, I'm assuming you've setup Twilio, if not, head over to and sign up:
https://www.twilio.com/

You'll want to add the Twilio ruby client in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'twilio-ruby'
```

Be sure to bundle install and if everything is good, you are ready to code your Twilio interaction.  Assuming from fn1 you have the data in a variable, you'll now need to send it via SMS/MMS, here's the Twilio guide for that:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms/sending-via-rest

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  (Tried to vote this up, but don't have enough credit / brownie points).