# Rails Regex Finding values on new lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, xml

I am having trouble with a simple regex task. The string looks something like this:

```
a = "<InstanceIdentifier>ac1aabd9000048fd0000005b1499825426437</InstanceIdentifier>\n\rInstanceIdentifier>7B8FB4781849AAB8C8ECBEA488FF5BF7</InstanceIdentifier>"
```

I'm trying to extract the value 7B8FB4781849AAB8C8ECBEA488FF5BF7 out of the string with

```
a.match(/<InstanceIdentifier>(\w+)<\/InstanceIdentifier>/i)
```

But this is obviously only matching the first one. I have tried a lot of things. Using Rubular, I've tried it with the '.+' operator using the 'm' option. Can anyone help me here?

**Edit**: Ok, so this is a XML communication, i'm sending them XML and they're apparently sending XML back. When they hit my Rails controllers, here is what params looks like. A mess.

https://gist.github.com/ruevaughn/090312182b96e0fb6f3422f2a6f993d9

So, since in the beginning I didn't need to do anything with this code, I just formatted it nicely so I could view the output, since the last few lines was all I needed to see, whether error or success.

This code:

```
message = ""
params.each do |k,v|
   message << k
   message << v
end

puts message
```

Generates this 'cleaner' string.

https://gist.github.com/ruevaughn/a85bcf51d498c439bccebc7d8ade749b

Now, I have the requirements to store in the database whether or not this was an error or success, and since this was done in a background job, the only way I have to tie back to the original database item is this instance identifier.

So I didn't want to have to parse the XML. But it looks like I might have to go that route. I have done a good amount of XML creation but I don't know how to parse the XML from those params. Any suggestions on that part?

Comment: Do not use regex to read XML.  Parse it  out with an XML tool. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198239/parsing-xml-with-ruby

Comment: How did you get the XML snippet? With an XML parser? If so, you should definitely extract the value you want with the XML parser, it will be much easier.

Comment: Ok, see edit I gave some more context. The Params I received back were extremely messy, and I wasn't sure how to parse them to XML so I turned them into a readable string. Any extra info on converting those params to XML?

Comment: This is not "a simple Regex task". XML is not a regular language, therefore it is not amenable to processing using regular expressions. Use an XML parser and XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
a = "<InstanceIdentifier>ac1aabd9000048fd0000005b1499825426437</InstanceIdentifier>\n\r<InstanceIdentifier>7B8FB4781849AAB8C8ECBEA488FF5BF7</InstanceIdentifier>"
a.scan(/<InstanceIdentifier>(\w+)<\/InstanceIdentifier>/i) { |match| puts match }
# ac1aabd9000048fd0000005b1499825426437
# 7B8FB4781849AAB8C8ECBEA488FF5BF7
```

if you're set on using a regex for this, though as mentioned an XML parser would be a better way to go about this. Do note, that test input you gave us

```
a = "<InstanceIdentifier>ac1aabd9000048fd0000005b1499825426437</InstanceIdentifier>\n\rInstanceIdentifier>7B8FB4781849AAB8C8ECBEA488FF5BF7</InstanceIdentifier>"
```

is incorrect, though that looks like a hand-modified example and probably just a question-typo (based on your gist links). (You're missing the open `<` on the second `<InstanceIdentifier>`

Comment: You are right, I was missing the < thanks. I will try that

Comment: I had tried Scan, but I didn't realize I could pass it a block. Sweet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the multi-line flag "m"

```
a.match(/<InstanceIdentifier>([^\n]\w+)<\/InstanceIdentifier>/mi)
```

Comment: I tried that, it still only matches the first instance