# How to loop xml nodes using ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, csv, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I have an XML file of 50MB. I need to parse it and convert to CSV.
Following is the `XML File`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<IAPDFirmStateReport GenOn="2019-01-02">
<Firms>
<Firm>
<Info FirmCrdNb="146099" BusNm="PRINCIPA FINANCIAL ADVISORS" LegalNm="CHUNG, BUCK CHWEE"/>
<MainAddr Strt1="15111 WHITTIER BLVD" Strt2="STE 420" City="WHITTIER" State="CA" Cntry="United States" PostlCd="90603" PhNb="562-945-7888" FaxNb="562-968-1885"/>
<MailingAddr/>
<StateRgstn>
<Rgltrs>
<Rgltr Cd="CA" St="APPROVED" Dt="2008-03-13"/>
</Rgltrs>
</StateRgstn>
<ERA>
<Rgltrs/>
</ERA>
</Firm>
<Firm>
<Info FirmCrdNb="170562" SECNb="802-112318" BusNm="ALUMNI VENTURES GROUP" LegalNm="LAUNCH ANGELS MANAGEMENT COMPANY, LLC"/>
<MainAddr Strt1="788 ELM ST" City="MANCHESTER" State="NH" Cntry="United States" PostlCd="03101" PhNb="603-518-8112"/>
<MailingAddr Strt1="889 ELM ST" Strt2="3RD FLOOR" City="MANCHESTER" State="NH" Cntry="United States" PostlCd="03101"/>
<StateRgstn>
<Rgltrs/>
</StateRgstn>
<ERA>
<Rgltrs>
<Rgltr Cd="MA" St="ACTIVE" Dt="2014-02-24"/>
<Rgltr Cd="NH" St="ACTIVE" Dt="2018-07-23"/>
</Rgltrs>
</ERA>
</Firm>
<`/Frims>`
```

------Almost having 90 Firm tags

So, I need to parse it dynamically using ruby and convert it into CSV. How can I figure out this?

Comment: What have you tried? If you're running out of memory you might need SAX

Answer (score 1):

Look at this question - [Parsing XML with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198239/parsing-xml-with-ruby)

You may also use Ox gem which is not mentioned in above question - take a look here:
https://github.com/ohler55/ox#parsing-xml-into-a-hash-fast

Once you will have your `XML` converted to `Hash` you should easily convert it to `CSV`.