# Ruby Nokogiri XML Parsing for NodeSet

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm having an issue with parsing some `XML` using `Nokogiri` in `Ruby 2.6.5`.  I've checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198239/parsing-xml-with-ruby) and other posts, but I still can't seem to get the `Nokogiri` bit to take.  I've tried different nodes, all with the same result of *thing* being `NilClass`.

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml_str = <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <description><![CDATA[powered by <a href="http://www.wordpress.org">WordPress</a> &amp; <a href="https://www.mapsmarker.com">MapsMarker.com</a>]]></description>
    <open>0</open>
    <Style id="bar"><IconStyle><Icon><href>http://epic-curiousity.com/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/bar.png</href></Icon></IconStyle></Style>
    <name>Epic Curiousity</name>
    <Placemark id="marker-35">
      <styleUrl>#bar</styleUrl>
      <name>Brasserie de Rochefort</name>
      <TimeStamp><when>2014-06-13T07:06:01-08:00</when></TimeStamp>
      <atom:author><atom:name>epiccuri</atom:name></atom:author>
      <atom:link rel="related" href="http://epic-curiousity.com" />
      <description><![CDATA[The Brasserie de Rochefort is located inside the Abbey of Notre-Dame de Saint-Rémy in Rochefort.  They're a trappist brewery and produce three very-fine beers:<ul><li>Trappistes Rochefort 6 - Dubbel 7.5% ABV</li><li>Trappistes Rochefort 8 - Belgian Strong Dark Ale 9.2% ABV</li><li>Trappistes Rochefort 10 - Quadrupel (Quad) 11.30% ABV</li></ul>You can find the brewery's homepage here: <a href="http://www.trappistes-rochefort.com/">http://www.trappistes-rochefort.com/</a><br /><br />Their BeerAdvocate page is located here: <a href="http://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/207/">http://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/207/</a>]]></description>
      <address><![CDATA[Brasserie Scaillet, Rue de la Griotte, Rochefort, Belgium]]></address>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>5.199692,50.175346</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
EOF

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_str)
puts doc.class                      # => Nokogiri::XML::Document
thing = doc.at_xpath("Document")
puts thing.class                    # ==> NilClass
```

Anybody know why this isn't being recognized as a nodeset?  I've tried with this as well with the same results:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml_str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to that the xml has namespaces and these needs to be included in xpath query:

```
document = doc.at_xpath('//xmlns:Document')
document.class 
 => Nokogiri::XML::Element

document_name = doc.at_xpath('//xmlns:Document/xmlns:name')
document_name.class 
 => Nokogiri::XML::Element
document_name.content
 => "Epic Curiousity"
```

To get a name in atom:name:

```
atom_name = doc.at_xpath('//atom:name')
atom_name.content
 => "Epic Curiousity"
```

Comment: Perfect.  Are there any Nokogiri notes on this?  I find the documentation lacking.  Thank you.

Comment: The tutorial on the nokogiri.org website has a bit about searching with namespaces: https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces

Comment: I completely missed that.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I see on [docs](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) that you can use `css` to find what you want

```rb
puts doc.at_css("Document")
# show all node Document

puts doc.css("name")
# <name>Epic Curiousity</name>
# <name>Brasserie de Rochefort</name>

puts doc.css("Placemark name")
# <name>Brasserie de Rochefort</name>

puts doc.css("Document/name")
# <name>Epic Curiousity</name>
```

Comment: OK, I should have tried that.  I immediately went for `xpath` because it was proper `XML` and had no `css`.  But it does indeed work.