# Using Nokogiri to parse HTML with xhtml:link tag?

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri gem to parse HTML data.

```
$ gem list nokogiri

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

nokogiri (1.6.2.1)
```

Sample HTML is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <xhtml:link>
      <div>
    Some content.
      </div>
    </xhtml:link>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting

```
>>  doc.xpath('/html/body/xhtml:link/div')
Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Undefined namespace prefix: /html/body/xhtml:link/div
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:159:in `evaluate'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:159:in `block in xpath'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:150:in `map'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb:150:in `xpath'
    from (irb):95
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

A full sample live HTML page can be found [here](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/40-Indians-kidnapped-in-Iraqs-Mosul/articleshow/36746485.cms)

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Not the actual problem, but it seems you have missed to close the `body` tag.

Comment: can you not `doc.xpath('/html/body/link/div')` it?

Comment: I get the xpath by inspecting elements from Firebug. This works for other documents but whenever there is a colon ':' in an element tag, it gives the said error.

Comment: Are you parsing as HTML or XML? If you parse as HTML then Nokogiri strips of namespaces, so you can just use `link`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the XML Namespace (`xhtml` in your example) to your root element so that Nokogiri recognizes it, unless you do that Nokogiri will ignore it and that error will appear.

You can do it this way:

```
<html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <xhtml:link>
            <div>Some content.</div>
        </xhtml:link>
    </body>
</html>
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840636/368167) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12470452/368167) answers.

**UPDATE based on comment**

I've reviewed Nokogiri docs and found two workarounds, one is to pass the namespaces:

```
doc.xpath('/html/body/xhtml:link/div', 'xhtml' => 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
```

Another is to manually add that namespace to the root document:

```
doc.root.add_namespace 'xhtml', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
doc.xpath('/html/body/xhtml:link/div')
```

While both ways *do* silent the error, the query in both cases just returns an empty array for me, unlike what happens if the `xmlns` attribute was originally included in the document.

Comment: I cannot modify the existing HTML because it comes from an external source. So can I provide the namespaces to Nokigiri so that it can resolve without I modifying HTML content ?

Answer (score 0):

You can *ignore* namespaces, if you are sure there are no unprefixed elements with the same name in the same context. Namespaces affect element and attribute *names*. If you select them using `node()`, or `*` you can test for the `local-name()` in a predicate without having to deal with namespaces.

In your example, you can select the `xhtml:link` element by selecting *all* elements in the context of `body`, and then restricting the result set to only those which have a *local-name* equal to `link`:

```
doc.xpath('/html/body/*[local-name()="link"]/div')
```

You *might* select unwanted HTML `<link>` elements if they occur in the body (they should never be there, but HTML parsers don't care if they are). But if they occur, they should be  empty elements. There will never be one with a `<div>` inside, so you're safe.

Comment: You can easily remove namespaces by using [`doc.remove_namespaces!`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-remove_namespaces-21).